# FluentNHibernate IDctionary with manytomany

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many

I have a mapping structured in this way:
public class Person

```
{
   public IDictionary<bool, Action> Actions { get; set; }
}

public class Action
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Map for Person

public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
   public PersonMap()
   {
      Id(x => x.Id) ...
      Map(x => x.Name) ...
      Table("Persons")
   }
}

// Map for Action

public class ActionMap : ActionMap<Action>
{
   public ActionMap()
   {
      Id(x => x.Id) ...
      Map(x => x.Name) ...
      Table("Actions")
   }
}
```

What I need to do now is this.
I need a third table that will contains this fields:

PersonId
ActionId
True/false

Because I have the collection of actions inside the class person i was thinking about using a manytomany, but I can't find documentation on how to map an IDictionary.
Any idea? Wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if you've already found the solution but there's been a recent update(only a couple weeks ago) where you could simply map it as `HasManyToMany(x => x.NameOfDictionary)` so you might want to update your FNH.

I haven't tried it yet though but here's the link: [mailing list post](http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/5b20b25934507d55)

Comment: Thanks I am gonna have a look and see if it's available in the latest built.
Thanks again